# Reminder to join the community discord for more vivid discussions!

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, discord

https://discord.gg/aDGVEBRx24

#advantages:

voice chat
live chatroom
you can direct message people who are also on the server
start polls
practice a presentation (just tell us you want to schedule an event) etc.

Comment: This came up in the close-vote review queue, and personally I don't have a problem with advertisements that are clearly related to OR, as long as the rest of the community doesn't have a problem with it, so I voted to "keep open".  But I think the community here would feel better about this if  the format and style of this ad were a bit more professional: not just dropping a URL down in the first line, and using a hash symbol (which is just uncommon in the Stack Exchange community, compared to other communities such as Twitter and Facebook).